# flip a table sql server with dynamic columns and fix rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

after a lot of join and group by i have come to the totals that i wanted...
to keep things simples i will reduce the complexity of the table..
lets say that i have this table that give me the totals of models per year/mont

```
YearMonth| Totals|model
------------------------
2015-05 | 70    |AA
2015-05 | 50    |BB
2015-06 | 30    |AA
2015-06 | 10    |BB
------------------
201x-yy | 33    |AA
201x-yy | 90    |BB
```

i have to create a specific (non convencional)graphic in excel with this data
but the only way is to transform the table to something 
where the columns are dynamic and the rows fix... something like this

```
Model|2015-05|2015-06|----|201X-yy
------------------------------------
AA   | 70    | 30    |--- |33
BB   | 50    | 10    |----|90
```

is it possible to create with a query? or do i have to do it use some complex store procedure to first create a temp table and than insert data into it.

Answer (score 0):

Me recommendation in this case is to return that data into Excel, and use Excel pivot table to get your output. You can tell Excel to return a linked quiet directly to a pivot table.